# has facebook again allowed to fetch friendlist of a user?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, facebook, facebook-graph-api

On recent research facebook provide this new method to fetch frendslist.

```
FBSDKGraphRequest *request = [[FBSDKGraphRequest alloc]
                           initWithGraphPath:@"/{user-id}/friendlists"
                                  parameters:params
                                  HTTPMethod:@"GET"];
[request startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBSDKGraphRequestConnection *connection,
                                  id result,
                                  NSError *error) {
// Handle the result
}];
```

> me?fields=id,name,friendlists

But it is returning empty data element.
is there any other way or somthing

Comment: ya you can fetch only ID and name  in Friendslist

Comment: how can i do that...kindly tell the procedure...

Comment: This will only give you the id and name of the _lists_ a user has. It does _not_ give you access to the users that are _on_ those lists.

Comment: @CBroe and Anbu.Karthik-- by using the parameter id...can I be able to send invites or messages to the selected users using ID ....?

Comment: Your possibilities to let users invite people to your app are listed here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/faq#friend_invite

Answer (score 3, accepted):

do like

Initially you  need to pass the permission parameter `user_friends` at the time of login.

```
FBSDKGraphRequest *request = [[FBSDKGraphRequest alloc] initWithGraphPath:@"/me/friends" parameters:@{@"fields": @"name",@"id",@"picture"} HTTPMethod:@"GET"];
                 [request startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBSDKGraphRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {

                     NSLog(@"request friend list:%@", result);
                 }];
```

Comment: By using the parameter id ....are we able to do or get some things like send invites or messages or any liks share with the selected users or something ?

Comment: i am using the same code you provided just with a little change in ""parameters:@{@"fields": @"name, id, picture"}"" as ,(error giving when using comma) ......friends count is coming accurately, but empty data array object is coming empty.

Comment: if your friend use in your app after that you get id  , name else you wont get

Comment: ohkk so this was still the limitation afterall... actually i want to make a custom view to send invite to the facebook friends......

Comment: @ParvBhasker -- this is not related to your current question , if you need ask another question else stack overflow close your questions., If my answer is useful give the upvote and check mark it is useful for future user also